# How can I make this formula dynamic

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In a spreadsheet, I have five columns with the following headings

- "Product Code" in cell B3
- "Product Description" in cell C3
- "Dozens per case" in cell D3
- "Cases per pallet" in cell E3
- "UOM" in cell F3 (which means Unit of Measure)

On my user form, I have a combo box that the user will select the product from, a command button and a text box. The values of that combo box are populated from the spreadsheet Product Code column.

Once the user selects the product from the combo box and enters a value in the text box (called "txtbxdz") and clicks the command button, a formula will be performed.

Currently the values are hard coded into the program as shown in the formula below.

```
Private Sub cmdbtnPrint_Click()

    Dim textValUp As Long
    Dim textValDown As Long
    Dim txtUOM As String
    Dim txtCs As Long
    Dim txtDz As Long        

        Case Is = "4120-5-01 (ALLERGY 180MG 5CT)"
            txtDz = 2
            txtCs = 200
            txtUOM = "DZ"
    End Select

    textValUp = ((txtbxdz.Value) / txtDz / txtCs) + 0.5 - 1E-16
    textValDown = ((txtbxdz.Value) / txtDz / txtCs) - 0.5 + 1E-16

End Sub
```

Comment: So the question is, `How do I make so and so variables dynamic?` If so, please [edit] the question to actually include a *question* :)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking but the more I stare at it, the more I figure you want to take the hard coding out by passing variables into the function?  So you want to pass variables "into" your Sub so you can use the same sub but pas in "the search string", txtDz, txtCs, and txtUOM come from the worksheets cell values, maybe?  You could pass a selection target into the Sub and then offset function to the adjacent cells for the info, like a row selection . . . . need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I understand your answer correctly. If I recall correctly what a VLookup does similar to that. Let me give an example. If the user selects the 4120-5-01 (Allergy 180mg 5ct) from the combo box , an unknown line of code at this point, will loop through the product description until the code finds the product, then I guess offsets to the column that holds the values that corresponds to that product and assigns that value to the appropriate variable. 
So if  Product name is located in cell C3
The code will offset 1 to the right get
the value of "Dozens per case" in cell D3
and assign it to txtDz and offset it again by 1 and assigns the value in E3 to txtCs and so on.